# Custom verificarion email in laravel issue

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-6, email-verification

guys in my laravel application i'm trying to send my users a custom verification email, as i'm using language translations

So as the first step I've created following custom email template in my `App/Notifications` folder `CustomVerifyEmailNotification.php`

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Auth\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class CustomVerifyEmailNotification extends Notification
{
    /**
     * The callback that should be used to build the mail message.
     *
     * @var \Closure|null
     */
    public static $toMailCallback;

    /**
     * Get the notification's channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array|string
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Build the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $verificationUrl = $this->verificationUrl($notifiable);

        if (static::$toMailCallback) {
            return call_user_func(static::$toMailCallback, $notifiable, $verificationUrl);
        }

        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject(Lang::get(''.('sentence.Hello friend. Verify Email Address').''))
            ->line(Lang::get(''.('sentence.If you did not create an account, no further action is required.').''));
    }

    /**
     * Get the verification URL for the given notifiable.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return string
     */
    protected function verificationUrl($notifiable)
    {
        return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
            'verification.verify',
            Carbon::now()->addMinutes(Config::get('auth.verification.expire', 60)),
            [
                'id' => $notifiable->getKey(),
                'hash' => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification()),
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Set a callback that should be used when building the notification mail message.
     *
     * @param  \Closure  $callback
     * @return void
     */
    public static function toMailUsing($callback)
    {
        static::$toMailCallback = $callback;
    }
}
```

and following is my `User.php`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Cashier\Billable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable,Billable;
    use HasRoles;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    protected $fillable = [
        'name','last_name', 'email', 'password','username','mobile','propic','user_roles','user_source',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

How can I inject my custom email template here?

I'm using laravel 6 and following is my `MustVerifyEmail.php` trait

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Auth;

use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail;

trait MustVerifyEmail
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user has verified their email address.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasVerifiedEmail()
    {
        return ! is_null($this->email_verified_at);
    }

    /**
     * Mark the given user's email as verified.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function markEmailAsVerified()
    {
        return $this->forceFill([
            'email_verified_at' => $this->freshTimestamp(),
        ])->save();
    }

    /**
     * Send the email verification notification.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
    {
        $this->notify(new VerifyEmail);
    }

    /**
     * Get the email address that should be used for verification.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmailForVerification()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

Current verification process works properly but I need to send that customized email to my users.

Comment: It is pretty standard to put custom classes in your own namespace. So for your custom notification, something like `App/Notifications`, and your trait `App\Traits`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you have to ovewrite `sendEmailVerificationNotification()` function in order to use your Notification `CustomVerifyEmailNotification`.

So, in your `User.php` you have to write a function `sendEmailVerificationNotification` like:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Notifications\CustomVerifyEmailNotification; // use your custom Notification
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Cashier\Billable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable,Billable;
    use HasRoles; 


    public function sendEmailVerificationNotification() 
    {
        $this->notify(new CustomVerifyEmailNotification);
    }
}
```

Then you can customize the email in your custom notification

Comment: I tried, but it gives me Class 'App\Notifications\CustomVerifyEmailNotification' not found

Comment: @VolkaDimitrev did you update the namespace in your custom notification (and dont forget to clear you cache)

Comment: i have namespace Illuminate\Auth\Notifications;, is it correct?

Comment: oh i fixed the issue now, yeah, namespace was the issue :)